# Assign values to chars

Tags: c++, dictionary

Is there an easy way in C++ to assign value to char? I want to get list of chars, and connect them to a value for example:

- a - true
- b - true
- c - false
- r - true

is there any simple way just like the Dictionary in C#?

Comment: You can use a std::map<char,bool> perhaps?

Comment: Your terminology is somewhat confusing. Assigning a value to a `char` means `char c; c = 'x';`.

Comment: @juanchopanza:  I thought so too.  The  demonstrated use case and the use of the word "dictionary" led me to believe he was looking for some kind of associative container.  Was just a guess though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest C++ analogue to a "Dictionary" type object is an [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map <char, bool> myDictionary;
  myDictionary ['a'] = true;
  myDictionary ['b'] = true;
  myDictionary ['r'] = false;
}
```

You can search for the presence of items:

[C++11]

```
auto it = myDictionary.find ('x');
assert (it == myDictionary.end()); // not found

it = myDictionary.find ('a');
assert (it != myDictionary.end());  // found
assert (it->second == true); // assert that a is mapped to true
```

Comment: @sftrabbit:  The edit history suggests you removed my link, but the link is still active.  What did you actually change?

Comment: You had the code quotes around the link, so it wasn't working properly. I put them inside.

Comment: @Downvoter:  I'd love to know why you disagree with this answer.